# Validation error on the label text and input border

Tags: javascript

Using Javascript, I have input validation, when it's empty and click outside the input, it shows an error or red color on the border and label input. I know when we use query selector all, we need to create loops, in my case, the input validation works, it shows red border, however, the label input only shows once, only on the first name.

I tried to add query selector all on the textInput variable, but doesn't seem to work as well, please advice.

```js
const userInput = document.querySelectorAll(".inputJs");

      userInput.forEach(function(evt) {
        evt.onblur = function() {
          const textInput = document.querySelector(".guestlist-form-label");

          if (evt.value === "") {
            evt.classList.add("has-error");
            textInput.classList.add("has-error");
          } else {
            evt.classList.remove("has-error");
            textInput.classList.remove("has-error");
          }
        };
      });
```

```css
.guestlist-form-label.has-error {
  color: red;
}

.inputJs.has-error {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.guestlist-form-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 62%;
}

.guestlist-form-wrapper-input {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 48%;
  margin-top: 25px;
}

.guestlist-form-wrapper-input label {
  color: #9b9b9b;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.guestlist-form-wrapper-input input {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #9b9b9b;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #000;
}

.guestlist-form-wrapper-input input:focus {
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid #4990e2;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 rgba(73, 144, 226, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 rgba(73, 144, 226, 0.4);
}
```

```html
 <form id="app" class="guestlist-form-wrapper">
        <div class="guestlist-form-wrapper-input">
          <label class="guestlist-form-label">First Name *</label>
          <input type="text" class="inputJs">
        </div>
        <div class="guestlist-form-wrapper-input">
          <label class="guestlist-form-label">Last Name *</label>
          <input type="text" class="inputJs">
        </div>
        <div class="guestlist-form-wrapper-input">
          <label class="guestlist-form-label">Email *</label>
          <input type="email" class="inputJs">
        </div>
        <div class="guestlist-form-wrapper-input">
          <label class="guestlist-form-label">Phone *</label>
          <input type="tel" class="inputJs">
        </div>

      </form>
```

Comment: @Pete I tried: const textInput = document.querySelector(".inputJs").previousSibling; but it still shows once the text error, I think it's because I need to add loops as well in it, but I'm not sure how to implement it

Comment: I think you're problem is that you're selecting all labels instead of the label that belongs to your current input. In jQuery you would say `$(this)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your always going to have the same number of labels as inputs, you can get all labels using the query selector all and then use the index in the foreach to add a class to the corresponding label:

```js
const userInput = document.querySelectorAll(".inputJs");
const label = document.querySelectorAll(".guestlist-form-label");

userInput.forEach(function(evt, index) {
  evt.onblur = function() {
    const textInput = label[index];
    textInput.classList.remove("is-focused");

    if (evt.value === "") {
      evt.classList.add("has-error");
      textInput.classList.add("has-error");
    } else {
      evt.classList.remove("has-error");
      textInput.classList.remove("has-error");
    }
  };
  
  evt.onfocus = function() {
    const textInput = label[index];

    if (evt.value === "") {
      textInput.classList.add("is-focused");
    }
  };
});
```

```css
.guestlist-form-label.has-error {
  color: red;
}

.guestlist-form-label.is-focused {
  color: blue;
}

.inputJs.has-error {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.guestlist-form-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 62%;
}

.guestlist-form-wrapper-input {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 48%;
  margin-top: 25px;
}

.guestlist-form-wrapper-input label {
  color: #9b9b9b;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.guestlist-form-wrapper-input input {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #9b9b9b;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #000;
}

.guestlist-form-wrapper-input input:focus {
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid #4990e2;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 rgba(73, 144, 226, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 rgba(73, 144, 226, 0.4);
}
```

```html
<form id="app" class="guestlist-form-wrapper">
  <div class="guestlist-form-wrapper-input">
    <label class="guestlist-form-label">First Name *</label>
    <input type="text" class="inputJs">
  </div>
  <div class="guestlist-form-wrapper-input">
    <label class="guestlist-form-label">Last Name *</label>
    <input type="text" class="inputJs">
  </div>
  <div class="guestlist-form-wrapper-input">
    <label class="guestlist-form-label">Email *</label>
    <input type="email" class="inputJs">
  </div>
  <div class="guestlist-form-wrapper-input">
    <label class="guestlist-form-label">Phone *</label>
    <input type="tel" class="inputJs">
  </div>

</form>
```

Comment: btw is there a way to make the label shows blue when we click the input? so red when outside the input and blue when we click the input if it's empty, right now it's just keep showing red. I tried to add this code with onfocus, but doesn't seem to work: userInput.onfocus = function() {
        const textInput = label[index];

        if (textInput.classList.contains("has-error")) {
          textInput.classList.remove("has-error");
        }
      };